# suphp run files as different owner from same directory

Tags: php, suphp

I'm trying to use `suphp` to run `php` scripts as different users from within the same directory.

For example, I have `/var/www/` as the webroot which is owned by `www-data` and inside I have 2 files with different ownsers:

```
a.php (chmod 640, chown www-data:www-data)
b.php (chmod 640, chown test:test)
```

When I access `a.php` I have no problems, but when I access `b.php` I get a 500 error and the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` error of:

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:557: Directory /var/www is not owned by test
End of script output before headers: b.php
```

I've used this paradigm before with `suphp` which makes me think it's a new feature.

Can someone comment on how I can accomplish running `php` files with different owners from the same directory?

Comment: what are the permissions on /var/www (755 is what I would expect; if it's 750, that could be the problem although I suspect not).  Also, as a workaround, if you make a test directory (owned by test:test) and put b in there, does that work?

Comment: They are `755`, I also tried making a directory `test` already with the owner `test` and inside a file owned by `test`, but I get the same error.